# How to shell out from lamp stack environment on Debian

Tags: shell, debian, bitnami, lampp

I'd like to use the lampp stack environment for some reasons. So,
I do the following :

```
# Launch bitnami lampp stack (will start apache and mysql)
$ ./lampp/ctlscript.sh start

# load lampp stack environment
$ ./lampp/use_lampstack

# Do some operations with lampp stack mysql or apache
$ mysqldump -u root -p some_db > some_db.sql
```

And now, how to shell out from the bitnami lampp stack environment ?

```
# I tried the following without any result : 
$ ./lampp/use_lampstack deactivate
$ ./lampp/use_lampstack exit
$ ./lampp/use_lampstack quit
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `use_lampstack` script opens a new shell with the right environment for the stack. Once you're finished, you may simply exit the shell with the following command:

`$ exit`

You may also press `Control + d` instead of typing the previous command.

Once you do this, you will return to the parent shell.

Comment: The `use_lampstack` script contains the line: `exec bash --rcfile "/opt/bitnami/.bashrc"`. The `exec` built-in doesn't create a new process. Instead, it replaces the current program with `bash`. However, here, the current program is actually `/bin/sh`, which is interpreter of the script, as indicated by the shebang.
The end result when you run `use_lampstack` is that your current shell launches `/bin/sh`, which gets immediately replaced by `bash`. The script doesn't return until you end this instance of `bash`, either by executing `exit` or by closing the input with `CTRL + d`.